# Copy of string from one view to another view in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

hi i am new to iphone development.

I'm trying with sample where I need to copy a string from the textfield of viewController  and display it on the next view with a Label.

On the first view there is button bellow the textfield.1
I am not able to fix some issues showing `BAD ACESS` can anyone help me in solving this.
Let me know what i'm doing Wrong.

Thank you.

```
//copystring.h

@interface CopystringViewController : UIViewController{

    UITextField *myTextField;
    NSString *somestring;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *myTextfield;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *somestring;

-(IBAction)next:(id)sender;

//.m file

@synthesize myTextfield,somestring;


-(IBAction)next:(id)sender;
{

    NextView * next = [[NextView alloc] initWithNewString: myTextField.text];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController: next animated: YES];

}

NextView.h


@interface NextView : UIViewController{

    UILabel  *string2;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *string2;

- (id)initWithNewString:(NSString*)someString;


//.m file

@synthesize string2;


 -(id)initWithNewString:(NSString*)someString {

    string2 = someString;
 return self;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace method.it may run.

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender; {

    NextView * next = [[NextView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
    next.string2=myTextField.text;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:next animated: YES];

}
```

Comment: @jatin patel i did above changes but i am not able to display the  text entered in a textfield of first view to next view

Comment: @crazy2431 , Check it whether you are able to display text in same view. if no then bind your object with text field..

Answer (score 1):

hey string2 is a label so try string2.text = somestring;

```
 -(id)initWithNewString:(NSString*)someString {

string2.text = someString;

 return self;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you're assigning an NSString (someString) to a UILabel (string2).

AppleVijay's answer should do the trick.

If you don't like dot-notation in ObjC you can also write it like this:

```
[string2 setText:someString]
```

Answer (score 1):

U can declare ur somestring in to the delagate h/m file that way it wil be the global string. u can use it with appdaligateobj.stringname.

U dont evn need init u can directly add to viewdidload of next view.

string2.text = AppDalegateobj.stringName.

Comment: can u tel me with the code as i am new to development i am not getting it

Answer (score 1):

Delegation is the usual way to move data around like this. I wrote a very [simple example project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/DelegationExample.zip) to show this in action.

Answer (score 0):

You need init you view and retain you string:

```
-(id)initWithNewString:(NSString*)someString {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    string2.text = someString;
  }
 return self;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

/

```
/AppDelegate.h

NSString *String1;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * String1;

//AppDelegate.m
@synthesize String1

//ViewController1.h

AppDelegate * objAppDelegate;
UILable *lblstring;


@property (nonatomic, retain) UILable *lblstring;

//ViewController1.m
@synthesize lblstring

//On View Did Load.
objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
lblstring.text  = objAppDelegate.String1;
```